# Do Boltzmann Mechanics imply we're the only example of sentience in our observable universe?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, observable-universe

My understanding of BM is that the Big Bang was just a statistical event. Under this model, many Big Bangs occur which result in a 2-power distribution of universes; there are twice as many universes of size n bits as there are universes of size n+1 bits. An analogy would be a room full of air: there are twice as many events of size n molecules as there are events of size n+1 molecules. It's why there are so few events where large portions of the room lose air pressure. The larger the portion of the room, the rarer it is for that portion to lose air pressure. Most of the time, a room has a somewhat flat pressure distribution throughtout its total volume.

But this model has an implication. Because universes of size n bits outnumber universes of size n+1 bits by 2x, the vast majority of universes are small universes. But for us to perceive a universe, it must be large enugh to contain a sentience. So a sentience of size 8 bits can only exist in a universe of at least 8 bits. This means that if you are an 8 bit sentience, then you are twice as likely to be in an 8 bit universe than you are to be in a 9 bit universe. For you to meet another 8 bit sentience, you must appear in a universe of at least 16 bits which is 1 over 2 to the 8 times as likely as you appearing in a universe where you're alone. You, an 8 bit sentience, are 64 times more likely to be alone, then you are to have company. And that would just be for a small sentience. The sentience of the human species is about a trillion trillion bits meaning the chance that we're alone is 2 to the trillion trillion times greater  than the chance of us having company. The smarter you are, the more alone you are.

So my question is if BM does imply that we're almost certainly alone? Or did I not understand it?

Comment: "My understanding of BM is that the Big Bang was just a statistical event." Already these things aren't connected

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between "Boltzmann mechanics" which is presumably statistical mechanics, and [Boltzmann's idea that the universe came into being as a random fluctuation in a large thermal equilibrium world](https://www.nature.com/articles/051413b0) essentially producing a steady state universe. The first is a standard theory, the second is an interesting but controversial hypothesis.

One of the key problems with this later kind of "big world" model is that everything happens somewhere. Any observation compatible with some random chain of events leading to it with nonzero probability will occur and reoccur an infinite number of times. So this appears to undermine our ability to trust our own memories and observations (the Boltzmann brain problem), but also makes observations uninformative. There is a fair literature on this problem but as far as I can tell no consensus on how to neatly handle it. This ties in with problems about anthropic self-location.

The problem with the reasoning in the question is that while there is an exponential bias towards being in small worlds or being a short-lived random observer, the occasional ordered world emerging produce a bunch of normally evolved species and observers that are correlated with each other. The fact that you are surrounded by fellow humans rather than being a Boltzmann brain floating in space tells you something... unless you think you are a Boltzmann brain hallucinating mankind. And then we are back to how anomalous observers undermine our trust in physics. If you take your observations for granted, you have evidence that at least there are short-range correlations in the world that produce related intelligences to you as an observer.

That does not tell us much about the rest of the universe. We can observe that it is much larger than needed for our own existence, which again counts as an argument against us being in a tiny world just large enough to generate us (the prediction from the reasoning in the question). But we might still be in a giant world with a low natural probability of life or intelligence: there is nothing ruling it out.

One can claim the question is more philosophy than physics, but it is tied closely to many issues in how to think about the world statistically on a macroscopic scale - as well as the debate about whether this even can make sense.

Comment: One, anything other than the "controversial hypothesis" requires more assumptions since something fundamental would not be in that context. Two, you don't happen everywhere; you just happen in where you're likely to happen. I do agree that one implication is that you're most likely a close approximation of you (an imperfect you) than (perfect) you because close approximationn are more common than exact replicas. Three, I specifically referred to the sentience of the human species, not just my brain. Four, we live in a big universe so it's clear that sentience is more common in a big universe.